# Any good tutorial on Flutter google document AI?

Tags: google-api, flutter-dependencies, cloud-document-ai

I'm working on an end of year project that requires google document ai using flutter. I've combed the internet for any leads to no avail. So

i'm turning to the community to ask if anyone has any google link to tutorials on google document AI API.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some resources I found for how to use Google Cloud APIs with Flutter

- [Power-up your Flutter app with Google APIs | Session](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4MsuZiEezY)
- [Empowering Flutter Apps with Google Cloud Run - Brett Morgan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyEPDCvvEKE)

Here are some general resources for how to get started with Document AI

- [The Future of Documents - What is Document AI?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_jyoe1lQhg&list=PLIivdWyY5sqIR88BxIK-3w14Vm-jTH1id)
- [Document AI Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs)
- [Document AI How-To Guides](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/how-to)

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely challenging of finding specific resources for DocumentAI if you are a Dart/Flutter developer. I have created  samples that interacts with Google DocumentAI. You can check it out on GitHub [dart-documentai-samples.](https://github.com/bwnyasse/dart-documentai-samples/)

While it's not a Flutter app, the Dart code should give developers a solid foundation on how to work with the DocumentAI API. They can then integrate the logic into their Flutter applications. For anyone reading this answer, feel free to ask or raise an issue on GitHub!